# Insert grid template row (within grid) under condition

Tags: templates, grid, conditional-statements, zk, zul

In a facebook-esque fasion, I'm working in a post with comments. The comments have a int which indicates the id of the parent post. So Comment 1 and 2 both have assigned as parent Post 1.
What im working on is on displaying them as a grid within a grid. Here is that part in .zul:

```
<grid id="postGrid" height="550px" model="@load(vm.pcdata.posts)" emptyMessage="No Posts.">
    <template name="model">
        <row>
            <window border="normal">

                <!-- .................. -->
                <!-- PARENT POST -->
                <!-- .................. -->

                <caption id="userPost" label="@load(each.user)"/>
                <textbox id="infoPost" readonly="true" value="@load(each.info)" multiline="true" rows="4" width="100%" mold="rounded"/>
                <separator bar="true"/> 

                <hlayout>

                    <div>
                        <button label="Like" onClick="@command('addPLike', postid=each.postid)"/>
                    </div>

                    <div hflex="true">
                        <textbox id="likeTB" disabled="true" width="40px" style="text-align:center" value="@load(each.plikes)"/>
                    </div>

                </hlayout>

                <separator bar="false"/>

                <window border="normal">

                    <!-- .................. -->
                    <!-- THE SECOND GRID-->
                    <!-- .................. -->

                    <grid id="commentGrid" height="150px" model="@load(vm.pcdata.comments)" emptyMessage="No Comments.">

                        <template name="model">

                                <row>

                                    <window border="normal">

                                        <caption id="userComment" label="@load(each.user)"/>
                                        <textbox id="infoComment" readonly="true" value="@load(each.info)" multiline="true" rows="4" width="100%" mold="rounded"/>
                                        <separator bar="true"/> 
                                        <hlayout>

                                            <div>
                                                <button label="Like" onClick="@command('addCLike', commentid=each.commentid)"/>
                                            </div>

                                            <div hflex="true">
                                                <textbox id="likeTB" disabled="true" width="40px" style="text-align:center" value="@load(each.clikes)"/>
                                            </div>

                                        </hlayout></window></row></template></grid></window></window></row></template></grid>
```

In the second grid, I imagine there could be some sort of if function in which if both the postid in the father Post and the postsrc in the child Comment are the same, the comment will be displayed. Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: At the database level doesn't post-comment associate in a one-to-many fashion? If so, you can extract the data from the database and know that all comments can only be associated with their correct parent post.

Comment: @Col, im new to the entire database handling, i just know the theory. Where can i read about the One-To-Many and how to set it up?

Comment: A one-to-many is quite simple and common so a quick google search is going to give you better answers I can provide here. Also you can customise the search to make it more specific to the database you are using and whatever sql querying framework you may be using. The net result of this is that you don't need to verify that a comment will be for a specific post; all comments will be associated with their posts, and only their posts, when retrieved from the db.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shadow element `<if>`, e.g.

```
<if test="@load(vm.yourFlag)">
    <grid id="commentGrid">
    ....
</if>
```

please see http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/shadow_elements/flow_control.html

Comment: Ive found a solution!
Inside the first window, the parent post, i added this label:
<label id="postidlbl" value="@load(each.postid)"/>
and I modified the inner window like this:
<window border="normal" if="${postidlbl.getValue()==each.postsrc}">
the only problem is that, once the grid is created, it leaves empty spaces. how do i solve those empty spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `commentGrid` is created but inner window is hidden, so there is space inside `commentGrid`, right?

Since you specify `emptyMessage` on `commentGrid`, it should show `no comments`. Or there are still comments but all hidden? If so, you can consider hide both `commentGrid` with inner window.

Comment: it very literally has empty spaces as rows. For example, in my list of comments, if i add 4 and the second one added has a postsrc of 1, since it was the second one added, in the first post's list of comments there will be 1 empty row, then the comment one, and other two empty rows.
furthermore, if the post has no attached comments, there will be empty rows instead of "No comments"